# Laptop no longer boots with ubuntu 5.19.0-50 generic kernel after sudo apt-get update + upgrade and nvidia + cuda drivers installation

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I have a new Asus Vivobook Pro 14 (Core™ i7-11370H) laptop with a fresh Ubuntu installation. I ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`, then I installed the newest nvidia driver from Softwares & Updates -> Additional Drivers. These seem to work fine. Then nvidia-smi threw me an error, for which I found that I should run `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`, so I did. And then... kernel no longer boots, I get the message:

```
Gave up waiting for root file device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay (did the system wait long enough?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=.... does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

What I have tried:

1. I cannot even enter recovery mode for this kernel version.
2. I can boot normally from the other two versions (-46, -43)
3. The UUID matches the root properly.
4. After booting into the older kernel, I've purged any nvidia and cuda related things.
5. I also updated grub several times and reinstalled cryptsetup.
6. I recreated the initramfs with `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`

Neither of these helped. Any advice?

Comment: Your initrd seems to be borked. Maybe you could recreate it.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I've ran `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` but it didn't help

Comment: Please remove `quiet splash` from boot options, boot, make a picture, upload it here.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is at the GRUB menu, select the Ubuntu OS you are using and press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the command line.  Remove the options `quiet` and `splash`, and then press <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.

Boot logs should appear. You can examine these logs to see what the issue is.

Alternatively, you can use the package `bootlogd` which saves the logs into `/var/log/boot`. You can install it by using the command

```bash
sudo apt-get install bootlogd
```

and then view the logs using `nano /var/log/boot` or `cat /var/log/boot`.